# How did they know it was the Mogadorians who killed One, Two, and Three?

Tags: lorien-legacies, i-am-number-four

The book *I am Number Four* starts off with a bit of exposition about the nine Lorien Garde and how three of them are already dead. Four mentions that when One was killed, it was "the first sign that they'd found us" - the first time they knew for sure the Mogadorians were on Earth.

But **how did they know the deaths were due to the Mogadorians?**

What would have happened if One had died naturally, rather than being killed by a Mogadorian? I'm assuming the scar would still have appeared on the ankles of the others, that it represents death rather than violent death. Sure, it was *likely* that the death of a carefully protected Lorien Garde child would probably be a result of enemy action rather than accident, but why was Four so *sure*?

Comment: Does anyone really know enough about *I Am Number Four* to downvote this? ;)

Comment: @Adamant For about a year (minus one few-months-long period, I think), every one of my questions has gained exactly one downvote (or exactly two in one period), usually around the same time of day. I suspect it's more to do with the person who posted the question than the quality of the question ;-)

Comment: In _The Lost Files: Six's Legacy_ (chapter 3), Six says the following: _"Years had passed since One's death, without incident. It had gotten so easy to imagine it was a fluke. If we were feeling really hopeful, we could imagine One had died in an accident. That the Mogadorians hadn't caught our scent. That time is over. We know for sure now. The Mogadorians have found the second member of the Garde, and killed him or her [...] We know two deaths is no fluke. The countdown has truly begun."_ This indicates that Six only knows for sure about the Mogs finding them after Two's death.

Comment: Not sure about Four though.

Comment: @bcsb1001 Nice find! You could turn that into an answer :-)

Comment: In a planet of semi-peaceful aliens assume your enemies killed your friend.